# An infinite series $1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+.......}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

How can we find the value to which the following series converges, if it converges to a finite number? If else, how can we prove that it is divergent?$$1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+......}}$$

Comment: Can you see it as a sequence defined by induction?

Comment: No. I can't. I don't get your idea.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html Apparently, this is a number simply called the "continued fraction constant."

Comment: @user104014: it was a wrong idea.

Comment: @florence Oh! Thanks for the link. It completely explains all my doubts.

Comment: If it converges, it is towards an irrational number, cause the development of a rational number is periodic.

Comment: @SylvainJulien All simple continued fractions converge. The ones which are (eventually) periodic are roots of a quadratic, the ones which are finite, ie zero after a certain point are rational.

Comment: Thank you snulty for the information.

Comment: @SylvainJulien It's actually covered quite well in hardy and Wright. Or I'm sure it's in a lot of number theory books. The proof essentially shows that out of the odd and even terms one increases and the other one decreases (I can't remember which) and both have to meet at some limit.

Comment: @florence this one seems to be one over the continued fraction constant

Comment: @MJD Why adding the huge vertical space in a title?

Answer (score 2):

We can see that
$$
1 < 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+......}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{2} > \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+......}}
$$
so
$$
1 < 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+......}} < \frac{3}{2}
$$

Comment: you show that it is bounded but that does not imply that it converges

Comment: @miracle173 It would be easier or just as easy to show all simple continued fractions converge $\ldots$

Comment: It's bounded and we can define a sequence which decreases and get's asymptotically closer to it: $s_1=\frac{1}{1+0}$, $s_2= \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}$ and so on...

Comment: @Squirtle it doesn't decrease, it alternates above and below its limit. Check the next few terms